# If condition not working with strpos

Tags: php, function, strpos

I created custom function `OutputMessage` from where i'm inserting error message with its `ClassStyle` like this `Error: image upload failed!` and then i'm exploding string and split class from it add in to `div class` but my function is not working fine.

```
function OutputMessage($Message=''){
    if($Message){
        $Postion = strpos($Message,":");
        if($Postion !== TRUE){
            return sprintf('<div class="alert alert-default">%s</div>',$Message); 
        }else{
            $Message = explode(": ",$Message);
            return sprintf('<div class="alert alert-%s">%s</div>',strtolower($Message[0]),$Message[1]); 
        }
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

`$Position` check is not working because i'm passing Message with it's class but it's still returning default class

Comment: Which class do you mean?

Comment: Class Mean Stylesheet class like danger, success I'm passing string like this `Danger: image upload failed!`

Comment: so first it's find string position `:` if true then explode string and return message

Comment: I have also faced this situation some times but alternate i used `(strcmp($str1, $str2)>0)`.. and it was ok

Comment: After this line `$Message = explode(": ",$Message);` add `var_dump($Message)` and tell me what's coming up?

Comment: actually i have to check if it's found `position :` so then run with `custom class` otherwise run default clas

Comment: Right I understand. Can you get me what's the value of above code? ^^^

Comment: buddy it's not going to next process so i can `var_dump` it's still stuck in first process returning this message

Comment: It's work now i have found solution

Comment: $position can never be boolean true.  It will either be boolean false, or an integer indicating where the string starts in the haystack. use === FALSE instead of !== TRUE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual entry of strpos() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

which means that `if($Postion !== TRUE)` will always be `true`, as `strpos()` never returns `true`.

To make your function work as expected, change your `if` statement to `if($Postion === false)`.

Answer (score 3):

Why you can not achieve like this....

```
function OutputMessage($Message = NULL){
    if(is_null($Message){
        return;
    }
    else {

        $arr = explode(":",$Message);
        if(count($arr)>0){
            return sprintf('<div class="alert alert-%s">%s</div>',strtolower($arr[0]),$arr[1]); 
        }

       else {
            return sprintf('<div class="alert alert-default">%s</div>',$Message); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) you can see that the function will `NEVER` return true. Just change it to false in the if statement and everything would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The strpos() function returns the start position of the string as an integer or FALSE if the string does not exist. Your if else statement will therefore never hit the else statement as $Position will never be equal to TRUE.

Swap the if statement to check for FALSE `if($Position === FALSE)` then you should be able to get the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use greater then 0 instant of TRUE

```
function OutputMessage($Message=''){
if($Message){
    $Postion = strpos($Message,":");
    if($Postion < 0){
        return sprintf('<div class="alert alert-default">%s</div>',$Message); 
    }else{
        $Message = explode(": ",$Message);
        return sprintf('<div class="alert alert-%s">%s</div>',strtolower($Message[0]),$Message[1]); 
    }
}else{
    return "";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to achieve with this,

```
function OutputMessage($Message=''){
    if(is_null($Message) || $Message === ""){ return ""; }

    if(strpos($Message,":") === false){
       $result = sprintf('<div class="alert alert-default">%s</div>',$Message); 
    }else{
        $Message = explode(": ",$Message);
        $result = sprintf('<div class="alert alert-%s">%s</div>',strtolower($Message[0]),$Message[1]); 
    }
    return $result;
}
```